# SQL Server 2008 CAST('' AS XML) fails inside of CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use `CAST` for converting some table columns since my columns are different. For example one column was `VARCHAR(4)` and in new table it is `integer`. Data in the old table had numbers and letters concatenated together. For example 100M or 50NR or NR or 105. So I wrote a T-SQL `CASE` statement that should convert the data.

Here is example:

```
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('M',LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1))) <> 0 
         AND LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1)),'M','')) <> 0 
       THEN REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1)),'M','')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('NR',LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1))) <> 0 
         AND LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1)),'NR','')) <> 0 
       THEN REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1)),'NR','') 
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1))) <> 0 
         OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1))) = 0 
       THEN NULL
    ELSE 
       CAST('' as xml).value('sql:column("hs_ptr1") cast as xs:integer ?', 'integer')
END AS hs_ptr1
```

My code fails with this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NR' to data type int.

If I put `CAST` line of code out of `CASE` statement there is no error in conversion but that way I will lose some values. I'm wondering why `CAST` is failing inside of the `CASE` statement? Is there anything else that I can do to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You can't mix datatypes in a single column. You have some rows with character data and some with int. That means that it will attempt an implicit conversion of the value of every row to the datatype with the highest precedence which in this case will be int.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not mixing data types. My column is set to Integer and I'm cleaning/trimming original values to match the data type.

Comment: >>>My column is set to Integer<<< That's why the error tells you:  onversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NR' to data type **int**.

Comment: You are mixing datatypes. The first condition in your case expression is returning a string, so is the second. The third one is an explicit null so it will be typed later. But the last condition is using xml to cast as an integer. This means the datatype for that column, not the row, is int.

Comment: Since I'm mixing datatypes do you have any solutions for this problem? Should I use CAST ( AS INT ) around first two case statements? @SeanLange

Comment: You CANNOT cast as int first two rows, they contain smth like NR that cannot be converted to int, it's a string

Comment: But that's why I'm replacing any of those two combination of letters with an empty string...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to convert everything to `varchar` like this

```
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('M',LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1))) <> 0 
         AND LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1)),'M','')) <> 0 
       THEN REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1)),'M','')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('NR',LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1))) <> 0 
         AND LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1)),'NR','')) <> 0 
       THEN REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1)),'NR','') 
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1))) <> 0 
         OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_ptr1))) = 0 
       THEN NULL
    ELSE 
       cast(CAST('' as xml).value('sql:column("hs_ptr1") cast as xs:integer ?', 'integer') as varchar(10))
END AS hs_ptr1
```

After seeing the result maybe you'll have an idea why it could not be `integer`

Comment: But I need conversion to be an integer not varchar.

Comment: Just SEE THE RESULT. And try to understand that 'NR' cannot be converted to INT

Comment: You copied my code as your answer... I can read and I understand that 'NR' varchar can't be converted to an integer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I CHANGED your integer to varchar, so now the code can be executed, that is different from yours. And when you finally see the result, you'll understand. I HOPE at least you'll try to execute it now